# Inconsistent CQL Filtering w/ Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cql-filter, cql

I am trying to utilize Geoserver's geometric filters to show subsets of a large number of polygons, but am getting inconsistent results.

I am testing CQL statements in the 'Edit Layer' page on Geoserver, and viewing my changes on an OpenLayers layer preview page.

For example, the filter:

```
BBOX(geom, -11500000, 6500000, -11900000, 7260359)
```

works completely as expected, yet the filters:

```
BBOX(geom,-11200000, 6100000,-11300000,6200000)
DISJOINT(geom, POLYGON((-11800000 6550000, -11800000 6850000, -11500000 6850000, -11500000 6550000, -11800000 6550000)))
INTERSECTS(geom, POLYGON((-11800000 6550000, -11800000 6850000, -11500000 6850000, -11500000 6550000, -11800000 6550000)))
DWITHIN(geom, POINT(-11800000 6550000),100000,meters)
```

produce zero output even though they should all hit some polygons.

Geoserver accepts the filters as syntactically correct, and no errors are evident on the page, so I'm really at a loss as to why these sometimes work and sometimes do not.

Output from log after trying:

```
DWITHIN(geom, POINT(-11800000 6550000), 100000,meters)
```

`2016-08-31 12:42:39,991 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (CRSAuthorityFactory, CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY)
2016-08-31 12:42:39,993 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - CHECK  (CRSAuthorityFactory, CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): user provided a Class.
2016-08-31 12:42:39,993 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - CHECK  (CRSAuthorityFactory, CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): consider hint[last] AbstractEpsgMediator.
2016-08-31 12:42:39,993 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - THROW  (CRSAuthorityFactory, CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): could not find implementation.
2016-08-31 12:42:39,994 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-08-31 12:42:39,994 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:40,005 INFO [org.geoserver.gwc] - Saving GeoSeverTileLayer sksoil:polygon_filter_layer
2016-08-31 12:42:44,869 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-08-31 12:42:44,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:44,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:44,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:44,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:44,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2016-08-31 12:42:44,873 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2016-08-31 12:42:44,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2016-08-31 12:42:44,883 DEBUG [org.geotools.parameter] - Axis length mismatch.
2016-08-31 12:42:44,884 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    Palette = null
    Tiled = false
    SRS = EPSG:3857
    FeatureVersion = null
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=style_css_polygon]]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@8db4c08f]
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
    FormatOptions = {}
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Angle = 0.0
    Elevation = []
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-1.22457799832824E7 : -1.12836283302401E7, 6274575.95160879 : 7260359.37192455]
    ViewParams = null
    Transparent = false
    StartIndex = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    SldBody = null
    ValidateSchema = false
    Sld = null
    StyleUrl = null
    CQLFilter = null
    FeatureId = null
    Interpolations = []
    TilesOrigin = null
    Env = {}
    StyleBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    StyleVersion = null
    ScaleMethod = null
    Width = 749
    Height = 768
    Filter = null
    Time = []
    Buffer = 0
    Format = application/openlayers
    Filters = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:3857, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=-1.22457799832824E7,6274575.95160879,-1.12836283302401E7,7260359.37192455, VERSION=1.1.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=749, HEIGHT=768, LAYERS=sksoil:polygon_filter_layer}
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    Get = true
    BaseUrl = 
    Version = 1.1.0
    Request = GetMap
2016-08-31 12:42:45,895 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-08-31 12:42:45,896 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,896 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,896 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,896 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.`

**... followed by about 400 lines of "CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS only", then:**

`2016-08-31 12:42:45,918 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Processing 1 stylers for http://sksoil.usask.ca:polygon_filter_layer
2016-08-31 12:42:45,918 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Expanding rendering area by 2 pixels to consider stroke width
2016-08-31 12:42:45,919 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Querying layer http://sksoil.usask.ca:polygon_filter_layer with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[-1.2684108984285446E7 : -1.0844357212622067E7, 5824706.604963378 : 7710880.386819345]
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting LogicFilter
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting LiteralExpression
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,920 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,921 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2016-08-31 12:42:45,921 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting LiteralExpression
2016-08-31 12:42:45,921 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,921 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2016-08-31 12:42:45,921 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "skv3_prt_mapunit",encode(ST_AsBinary(CASE WHEN ST_HasArc("geom") THEN "geom" ELSE ST_Simplify(ST_Force2D("geom"), 1951.9912696689369, true) END),'base64') as "geom" FROM (SELECT 
  dss_v3_sk.poly_id, 
  dss_v3_sk.geom, 
  dss_v3_sk.hectares, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.text1, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.text2, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.phsym, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.pasteros, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.capblty, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.stone, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.zone, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.deeptill, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.stsym, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.sdgr, 
  substr(dss_v3_sk_prt.mapunit::text, 1, 2) AS skv3_prt_mapunit,
  dss_v3_sk_prt.mapumod, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.slope_rg, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.surfex, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.slpl, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.irrig, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.water, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.wind, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.salsym
FROM 
  public.dss_v3_sk_prt, 
  public.dss_v3_sk
WHERE 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.poly_id = dss_v3_sk.poly_id
) as "vtable" WHERE  (ST_DWithin("geom",ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-11800000 6550000)', -1),100000.0) AND "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-12684108.984285446 5824706.604963378, -12684108.984285446 7710880.386819345, -10844357.212622067 7710880.386819345, -10844357.212622067 5824706.604963378, -12684108.984285446 5824706.604963378))', -1))
2016-08-31 12:42:45,928 ERROR [org.geotools.jdbc] - Failed to execute statement SELECT "skv3_prt_mapunit",encode(ST_AsBinary(CASE WHEN ST_HasArc("geom") THEN "geom" ELSE ST_Simplify(ST_Force2D("geom"), 1951.9912696689369, true) END),'base64') as "geom" FROM (SELECT 
  dss_v3_sk.poly_id, 
  dss_v3_sk.geom, 
  dss_v3_sk.hectares, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.text1, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.text2, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.phsym, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.pasteros, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.capblty, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.stone, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.zone, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.deeptill, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.stsym, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.sdgr, 
  substr(dss_v3_sk_prt.mapunit::text, 1, 2) AS skv3_prt_mapunit,
  dss_v3_sk_prt.mapumod, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.slope_rg, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.surfex, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.slpl, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.irrig, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.water, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.wind, 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.salsym
FROM 
  public.dss_v3_sk_prt, 
  public.dss_v3_sk
WHERE 
  dss_v3_sk_prt.poly_id = dss_v3_sk.poly_id
) as "vtable" WHERE  (ST_DWithin("geom",ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-11800000 6550000)', -1),100000.0) AND "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-12684108.984285446 5824706.604963378, -12684108.984285446 7710880.386819345, -10844357.212622067 7710880.386819345, -10844357.212622067 5824706.604963378, -12684108.984285446 5824706.604963378))', -1))`

Comment: Turn up the logging level to GeoTools developer and add the output to the question

Comment: does your geom column have a srid?

Comment: Yes, the SRID is 3857

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a "sql view" (otherwise the vtable construct would not be there). Did you correctly configure the srid in the geometry column of the sql view?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my SRS handling setting (in Edit Layer) on GeoServer was set to 'Force declared'. And it did not get declared in my query, so GeoServer defaulted to -1, and tried to mix that with an SRID of 3857, resulting in the error about "mixed SRID geometries".

In any case, by changing the **SRS handling setting to 'Keep native'**, the problem is avoided, and CQL queries work fine.